# Is it appropriate to create a tag for each and every error message for a given software?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know how to deal with the [ora-01019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01019).

There is a [pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6010527) on that tag. And the tag was used in only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400520/microsoftodbc-driver-for-oracleoracleerror-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-f) posted today. But I removed it.

Now, I'm not quite sure it was right, as there are already a lot of [ORA-XXXXX] tags. So, is it appropriate to create a tag for each and every error message for a given software?

Comment: I don't think these tags are needed, it will just lead to a ton of oracle error message tags similar to what we have for mysql.  If I saw that tag, I'd probably remove it as well.  I also rejected the pending edit on that tag.

Comment: Similar case with Java runtime exceptions. Whats the usefulness of NullPointerException tag? Each case is just different programming error, so looking at questions related to this tag wont help you in any way.

Comment: @Gas: It will ease closing them all as dup :)

Comment: I don't think these tags are harmful at all. Tags are for categorisation and for non-generic error messages these can be very helpful for finding questions and getting the error out of the questioner.

Comment: I had a similar wiki edit in my review queue today as well. The tag was created a few hours ago! It would be great to have a definitive answer...  Every related question I have read on SE has different opinions and no conclusion.

Comment: @Gas: totally disagree about `NullPointerException` (and `NullReferenceException` in C#). These are specific issues, with a specific set of canonical questions, and any other questions with these tags are probably duplicates of the canonical questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it is appropriate to create a tag for each and every error message for a given software.

However, I don't think that's the situation here. You're not talking about error messages here, you're talking about specific, categorized error codes. You're also not speaking about creating a tag for *every* error code, just to those people are having issues with. Error code ORA-01019 (unable to allocate memory in the user side) is a different situation than ORA-12505 (TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor), they warrant different handling, and one can certainly be an expert on one of the tags but not to another one as well as interested in one tag but not in another one.

With a given error code it's a lot easier to find any solutions previously given, so they reduce noise as well. Of course you don't *have to* have a tag for it, but it makes finding related incidents easier.

I don't see a problem in having these tags, and I do see benefit in having them. Thus, I'd prefer keeping them.

(note: there are several good answers related to this on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code) as well)